# PHP Json Decode code not working dailymotion

Tags: php, json, api

I'm using php to decode dailymotion api for related videos but my code is not working.. If i replace "list" with any other word it works perfectly.. But i have to use the word list due to dailymotion api.. Anyone who can help?

```
$string='{"list":[
{
    "duration": 233,
    "id": "x2laq9v",
    "thumbnail_480_url": "http://s1.dmcdn.net/JsC-U/x480-8Xl.jpg",
    "title": "Heart Touch Mashup 2015 | Hindi latest Sad Songs | Very Sad Song"

},
{
    "duration": 239,
    "id": "x2laq9v",
    "thumbnail_480_url": "http://s1.dmcdn.net/JsC-U/x480-8Xl.jpg",
    "title": "title 2"
}
]}';

$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

 // array method
foreach($json_a[list] as $p)
{
echo '
     duration: '.$p[duration].'
     <br>title: '.$p[title].'
<br><br>';

}
```

Comment: Is that ` a mistype on your code ? Because is preventing the page to display clear code, and that wont work neither. Try to remove them from the beginning and the end.

Comment: Yes.. I mistakenly added it while posting Question.. But without it also code doesnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put quotes on the array :

```
foreach($json_a['list'] as $p)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have decoded the JSON string as an associative array. You need to access the elements by giving the key as a string. Otherwise, PHP will assume it as a constant.

So, change

```
foreach($json_a[list] as $p)
{
    echo '
    duration: '.$p[duration].'
    <br>title: '.$p[title].'
    <br><br>';
}
```

to

```
foreach($json_a["list"] as $p)
{
    echo '
    duration: '.$p["duration"].'
    <br>title: '.$p["title"].'
    <br><br>';
}
```

It should work fine, then.